# PHP tags. How to minimize the tags usage in php script

Tags: php, tags, strip

I am using an ask answer script on a website and it converts the headline title words into the search query tags automatically.

For example: "Who are you?" is converted into tags 'Who' 'are' and 'you' tags respectively. I want tags to be displayed only if the letters in the word are greater than 4. Is it possible?

I am not into php but I searched for the 'tags' in my script and have uploaded the result here http://pastebin.com/m670a1609. Kindly let me know which source file would help in achieving this..

Thanks!

Comment: That would take a while... :) Maybe you should think about hiring someone?

Comment: wow, that code truly looks messy

Comment: I agree on that, but I assume hiring is quite expensive as php is the toughest language. Maybe, I am wrong? :)

Comment: Hehe.. I have to agree on that. Code is messy and gets more messier when we try to edit it :)

Answer (score 1):

> I want tags to be displayed only if
>   the letters in the word are greater
>   than 4. Is it possible?

You can do like this:

```
 if (strlen($your_word) > 4)
 {
   // go ahead
 }
```

Comment: I am not sure where to add it but it didn't work out as script is quite complicated. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Surely it would be easier to directly ask the provider of the script for help. A quick Google search makes me believe that AnswerScript is a commercial package that comes with support.

Comment: I have asked them now.. the reason being they don't respond pretty well. Last time I asked them for the update and they never emailed the customer about new update nor answered by queries.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should be looking for something like

```
explode(' ', $title_words)
```

and not php tags. This function splits the variable $title_words into separate array elements using a space as a delimiter. More or less what that script does to that title.